# date validation in objective c

Tags: objective-c, validation

how do to date validation using  objective c

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the "[Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html)"?

In short you have a bunch of options:

1. NSDateFormatter
2. General string handling (e.g., pick out the first four characters for the year)
3. NSDateComponents

But without knowing more about your problem it's difficult to be very specific, hence my suggestion that you read the manual first.